Gaussian Process with RBF kernel when $_0=_1=0$ deterministically
I originally have a Gaussian process over $[0,1]$ with mean function $m(x)$ and covariance function being the RBF kernel. However, I actually know that $_0$ and $_1$ are $0$
deterministically. Is that possible to modify the covariance function a little bit so that it can still have quite smooth sample path. It's pretty similar to bridge brownian motion but we are using different covariance function because I'm trying to produce smooth sample path.

Yes this is possible and easily doable. You just need to condition on your constraint $X(0)=X(1)=0$, i.e. use a conditional mean and covariance function. See formula (2.19) in Rasmussen/Williams

This is amazing! Thank you so much for your help!
